# How to indicate expected dates and actual dates in a Gantt chart?

Tags: python, r, excel, plotly, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a Gantt chart which involves planned and actual start/end dates. I would like same tasks to overlap like:
[image]
So far this is my code.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-05', Finish='2009-02-15'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')
])
colors = {'Job A': 'rgb(220, 0, 0)',
          'Job C': (1, 0.9, 0.16), }

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col="Task", show_colorbar=True, group_tasks=True)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")  # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

This is the result:
[image: Gantt chart without overlapping colors]

How do I distinguish planned v. actual dates? Python, R and Excel solutions are welcome. Usage of Plotly in solutions is completely optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an R solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Task = factor(Task, rev(levels(factor(Task)))),
         yval = as.numeric(Task)) %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(xmin = Start, xmax = Finish)) + 
  geom_rect(data = filter(., Type == "Planned"), alpha = 0.5,
            aes(ymin = yval - 0.4, ymax = yval + 0.4, fill = "Planned")) +
  geom_rect(data = filter(., Type == "Actual"),
            aes(ymin = yval - 0.2, ymax = yval + 0.2, fill = "Actual"), 
            color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = c("deepskyblue4", "olivedrab")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq_along(levels(.$Task)),
                     labels = levels(.$Task)) +
  labs(title = "Planned versus actual job times", x = "Date") +
  coord_fixed(15) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
}
```

[image]

Your data should be in the following format for this:

```r
df
#>    Task      Start     Finish    Type
#> 1 Job A 2009-01-01 2009-02-28 Planned
#> 2 Job A 2009-01-05 2009-02-15  Actual
#> 3 Job B 2009-02-01 2009-03-15 Planned
#> 4 Job B 2009-02-10 2009-03-15  Actual
#> 5 Job C 2009-02-20 2009-05-30 Planned
#> 6 Job C 2009-02-22 2009-05-20  Actual
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what is `%>%` all about?

Comment: @user14773854 It's the most commonly used pipe operator in R. It passes the output of a function into the first argument of the next function. It's a neat way to avoid having to declare new variables or overwrite your original data, and very standard practice in modern R.

Comment: I don't know what you did in the aes function because I keep getting `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (18): ymin and ymax`

Comment: @user14773854 the data has to be in the format I showed at the bottom of the page. Inside `aes`, the variables should be column names within the passed data frame. The error you are getting suggests that you are passing vectors with different lengths, not data frame columns.

Comment: The resulting chart looks too squeezed. How do I widen it?

Comment: Remove the `coord_fixed` line, then re-run the code. Now, drag your plotting window to an appropriate size and shape.

Comment: I want to change one y axis label which takes up too much space. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Change it in the original data frame to whatever you want to see on the plot

Comment: How can I make it preserve the order from the dataset instead of alphabetic order?

Comment: What is `yval` and `yval - 0.4` , `yval + 0.4`, `yval - 0.2`, `yval + 0.2`?

Comment: When converting Task to factor at the start, try Task = factor(Task, unique(Task))

Comment: These specify the upper and lower edges of the rectangles

Answer (score 1):

You can use Plotly express if you update the width of the 2nd trace.

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Type="Plan", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
    dict(Task="Job A", Type="Actual", Start='2009-01-05', Finish='2009-02-15'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Type="Plan", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Type="Actual", Start='2009-02-23', Finish='2009-06-04')
])

colours = {}
colours['Plan'] =  'red' # or 'rgb(220, 0, 0)' for rgb colours
colours['Actual'] = 'blue'

fig = px.timeline(df,
                  x_start="Start", 
                  x_end="Finish", 
                  y="Task", 
                  color='Type',
                  color_discrete_map = colours
                     )

fig.data[1].width=0.5 # update the width of the secodn trace

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you set the colors?

Comment: @user14773854 I've updated the post to demonstrate how to add a colour map

Comment: How do I add x and y axis labels?

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/