# How to insert x axis labels in a Plotly timeline?

Tags: python, plotly

Using DougR's [code from the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72369739/14773854) in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72354057/how-to-indicate-expected-dates-and-actual-dates-in-a-gantt-chart/72369739):

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Type="Plan", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
    dict(Task="Job A", Type="Actual", Start='2009-01-05', Finish='2009-02-15'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Type="Plan", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Type="Actual", Start='2009-02-23', Finish='2009-06-04')
])

colours = {}
colours['Plan'] =  'red' # or 'rgb(220, 0, 0)' for rgb colours
colours['Actual'] = 'blue'

fig = px.timeline(df,
                  x="Date",
                  x_start="Start", 
                  x_end="Finish", 
                  y="Task", 
                  color='Type',
                  color_discrete_map = colours
                )

fig.data[1].width=0.5 # update the width of the second trace

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up

fig.show()
```

Using `x="Date"` gives me an error:

```
TypeError: timeline() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

Yet it works in other [charts](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/):

```
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="GOOG")
```

How can I add x and y axis labels to my timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the documentation of timeline: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.timeline.html

You should specify labels and pass a dictionary of corresponding names.

```
fig = px.timeline(df,
                  x_start="Start", 
                  x_end="Finish", 
                  y="Task", 
                  color='Type',
                  color_discrete_map = colours
                )
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title="Date") #to add a title to xaxis
```

Comment: What do you mean by col1?

Comment: the first column that you want to change the label of

Comment: Can you use it in the context of my question? Apply your answer using my dataframe

Comment: Edited the solution. Since you have multiple columns on the X axis, the labels appear when you hover on the plot.

Comment: Hmm... Not working.

Comment: you can add a title to xaxis, I just added it to the solution